# Can CORS be used with form post middleware in Openstack Swift?

Tags: cors, ajaxform, openstack-swift

I need to upload a file using AJAX to an Openstack Swift instance. In order to avoid sharing my auth token, I am using the [form post middleware](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/api/form_post_middleware.html). It works when I do the upload from a normal html form, but when I try to make it from javascript using [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) I get the obvious error in the javascript console `Cross origin request blocked: same origin policy disallows reading the remote resource in http://localhost:7000/v1/AUTH_container/container/files (reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' not present)`.

My container metadata is:

```
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Content-Length: 0
< X-Container-Object-Count: 44
< X-Storage-Policy: gold
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
< X-Container-Meta-Temp-Url-Key: changeme
< X-Container-Meta-Temp-Url-Key-2: changeme
< X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
< X-Container-Bytes-Used: 10788833
```

So, the `Access-control-allow-origin` is set and, in fact, it is being sent when I try to access the resource by authenticating the request with `X-Auth-Token` header. However, when I authenticate the request using form post middleware the headers of the response are:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 46
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 24 Dec 2015 11:05:49 GMT
x-trans-id: tx558c6847052542399b9ec-00567bd18d
```

and no `Access-control-allow-origin` header is present (making the request fail).

Is CORS feature in Openstack Swift not compatible with form post middleware, or am I missing something here?